# How do I get RGui (3.5.1) to display line numbers?

Tags: r, windows, line

This is probably really simple.

I just need R x64 (3.5.1) on Windows 10 to display line numbers when viewing a script.

I don't see the option in GUI preferences. Please help!

Comment: You can't. Use a real IDE or text editor. Rstudio, Visual Studio with RTVS, Notepad++, SublimeText, or even emacs and vim for that 70s cool chic.

Comment: Thanks! It was that simple.